# Rand(Min, Mx) Undefined Variable

Tags: php, mysql, random, undefined

Hi I have the following code:

```
private function doPreEventStart($user) {
    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '%{$this->curSlotId}'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
        ORDER BY resultid desc LIMIT 1");
    $this->MaxResult = $row['resultid'];
    

$row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
    where ResultPackage.slotid like '%{$this->curSlotId}'
    and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
    ORDER BY resultid asc LIMIT 1");
$this->MinResult = $row['resultid'];

$this->curResultId = rand($MinResult,$MaxResult);
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: MinResult in /var/www/html/betserver.php on line 539
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: MaxResult in /var/www/html/betserver.php on line 539

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the line 539 to reference the class variables you just created:

```
$this->curResultId = rand($this->MinResult, $this->MaxResult);
```

(note the added `$this->` before each)